# PHP: Login ERROR

Tags: php, authentication, undefined

I'm newbie in PHP. Currently I'm doing a LOGIN. I have an error saying that

"Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\checkbox\admin.php on line 4
You are Welcome "

But the "user" is already exist in my prcess_login.php.

Here's my code for main_login.php

```
Username :<input type="text" id="userID"name="username"><br/><br/>

Password : <input type="password" id="passID"name="password">

<input type="image" name="btnLogin" src="image/btnLogin.png" value="SignIn" onClick="this.form.action='process_login.php'; this.form.submit()">
```

Next is my process_login.php

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$username = $_POST["username"]; //Storing username in $username variable.
$password = $_POST["password"]; //Storing password in $password variable.


$match = "SELECT * from tblmembers WHERE fldUsername = '".$_POST['username']."' AND fldPassword = '".$_POST['password']."';"; 

$qry = mysql_query($match);

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($qry); 



if ($num_rows <= 0) { 

echo "Sorry, there is no username $username with the specified password.";

echo "Try again";

exit; 

} else {



$_SESSION['user']= $_POST["username"];

header("location:admin.php");

}
?>
```

And Lastly, the admin.php

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
session_start();
echo "You are Welcome ". $_SESSION['user'];
?>
```

in admin.php appears the error...I just copied that codes here

http://www.phptutorialforbeginners.com/2012/10/php-simple-login-form-php-tutorial-for.html

- I don't get it why its not getting the "user" in my process_login.php

Please help me... Thank you

Comment: use session_start(); at the top of "my process_login.php" as there is no session is being started and also in admin.php.. session_start() should be at the top of the page before any code.

Comment: Please don't just copy paste code without knowing what it does when handling user information. Your code is using a deprecated database api, is vulnerable to sql injection and stores passwords in plain text. And on top of that your code is also vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: notice isn't error, paste it in the front of file:
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE); and also missing session_start();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session_start the first line after the php tag.

Comment: @Mihai..Thank you.. :) I will not forget that what you said